# Can my current(soon to be old) employer contact my new company regarding the offer

Tags: new-job

Can my current(soon to be old) employer contact my new company regarding the offer ? Ie validate the offered package etc without my permission ?

Comment: Why would they do this at all (with or without your permission)?

Comment: How do they know about the new company?

Comment: And even if they did contact your new company, it's really up to that new company as to how they respond.  So it is your new company that you should be concerned about.

Comment: Told them got offered new role outside the business .... they asked what the offer was etc ....

Comment: So just wondered if I told them what the offer was can they contact to check ? As I know they will try to match

Comment: @Jamie: That offer is none of their business whatsoever. If they ask you what the offer is, you can say something vague like "it was good enough so I accepted it", and if they insist "it's not something that I'm willing to tell you.

Comment: @Jamie: It is rarely a good idea to accept a counter offer, so don't worry about what they offer.

Comment: Even if they ask, there is no reason whatsoever to actually tell them who the offer is with.

Comment: Can they contact? Yes, if you tell them who the new employer is, which you shouldn't. If you already did, can they ask about your package? Yes. Will the new employer tell them? Likely not, because they have nothing to gain there. Not clear what exactly you want help with.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the new company is very small the old company is unlikely to get in contact with somebody that has the offer info.

Larger companies will only confirm dates of employment, which doesn't apply to you because you haven't started. They will only supply salary info if the employee give permission. This is generally done when an employee wants to be able to give salary info to a bank for a loan. They won't give it out to old, current, new or potential employers. They only disclose it if you have explicitly identified the 'bank' that will be requesting the information.

If the new company did give this out I would not feel comfortable joining the company. They should have no reason for giving your salary information to a competitor.

Answer (score 0):

All employee information is confidential either by law or by company policy, especially the compensation package that your new employer is giving you.

Your new employer expects you not to discuss your compensation package with their staff, so I have difficulty imagining a scenario where your new employer is freely discussing your compensation package with your old employer. There could be restraint of trade issues if your new employer and your old employer are competitors.

And it does not make too much sense for your new employer to volunteer info your compensation package to your old employer. Why? So that your old employer comes up with a counter offer?

Comment: I'm curious about how you know that "Your new employer expects you not to discuss your compensation package with their staff", since that's something that in my experience varies from company to company.

Comment: @Moz - Every one of my employers has been consistent in not letting their employees discuss their compensation packages with other employees. The reason is that such discussions may create dissension among the staff as they try to figure out why some are better paid than others and the staff confronts the management. What's YOUR rationale for compensation packages being known to everyone?

Comment: I'm not questioning why an employer would do that, simply asking how you know that in this particular case the employer is doing so. I base that on the practice not being universal - for example in unionised workplaces and many hourly-wage workplaces pay rates are public. Even in the USA, some workplaces work that way. So to just assume that secrecy is required is IMO unnecessary. And then, outside the US even the secrecy requirement can be unenforcable or illegal.I'm asking rather than downvoting, because it may be that you have definite knowledge of the OP's situation.